# How to use params property of ActivatedRouteSnapshot to populate data differently in a component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Imagine a situation where we have a single component which has to be populated with data differently based on different url parameters coming in.

That is, consider the below url patterns:

```
1. http://localhost:4200/venues/5760665662783488 
2. http://localhost:4200/users/2gjmXELwGYN6khZgzaeWKmLtIDt2 
3. http://localhost:4200/revenue
```

Within the component, 
If i use ActivatedRouteSnapshot interface to log the parameters of my incoming urls,  i get below results:

```
1. {venueid: "5760665662783488"}
2. {userid: "2gjmXELwGYN6khZgzaeWKmLtIDt2"}
3. {}
```

Now, if i want to populate fields of my single component in three different ways based on the three different url parameters like above, how can do so?

I mean how can i populate differently for incoming venueid/userid/{}? Is there a method on the ActivatedRouteSnapshot interface to check the key of the params object?

I tried looking through the documentation for ActivatedRouteSnapshot interface but did not find an answer.

Snip of my code to log the url params:
`console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params);`

I would like to learn different ways to achieve this functionality if there exist few. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` has a `paramMap` property and the `ParamMap` class has the `.has(paramName)` method for this.

```
  if(myActivatedRouteSnapshot.paramMap.has('userid')) {
    ...
  }
```

Where `myActivatedRouteSnapshot` is the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` you speak of.

https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#paramMap
https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. If my question helped the community, can you upvote my question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [paramMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#paramMap) property of the [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) which returns a [ParamMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) object that has also a property [keys](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#keys).

So to log the parameter keys you use:

```
console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.keys);
```

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. If my question helped the community, can you upvote my question?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this..

```
const obj = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
    if (Object.keys(obj)[0] === 'venueid') {
      console.log('venueid match'); // load venueid data for the component
    } else if(Object.keys(obj)[0] === 'userid') {
      console.log('userid match'); // load userid data for the component
    } else {
      console.log('other match'); // load other data for the component
    }
```

But answer from @AlesD and @Robin De Schepper seems to be more sophisticated. So i will go with them.